# PingFederate RelayState with IdP-initiated SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, pingfederate, keycloak-services

When initiating login Keycloak sends a `relaystate` parameter in request. However after successful login PingFederate does not return this `relaystate`.

Weird thing is if I add a `TARGET` parameter to the PingFederate request URL, it will return the value of this parameter as `RelayState`. What am I missing?

```
https:/<pingfed>/idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=keycloak&TARGET=someURL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are triggering IdP-init SSO via the `/idp/startSSO.ping` endpoint, there is no `RelayState` parameter that's understood there. For the documented parameters available, see: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=edg1564003024358.html

`RelayState` is a SAML protocol parameter that would be more naturally handled via SP initiated SSO, by sending a SAML AuthnRequest to `/idp/SSO.saml2`.
More info on the protocol endpoints can be found here: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=jsa1564002999406.html

Comment: Not related to the OP, but interestingly enough other services such as Okta allow you to set a default relaystate for IdP initiated auth. I